# Windows Primary/Secondary DNS doesn't work

Tags: windows, networking, dns

My understanding was that the point of having 2 DNS servers configured was for redundancy, so that if one goes down or is offline for any reason (maintenance, failure, etc.) clients can connect to the second server and make their requests without any noticeable impact to the end user.

What I have noticed however is that Windows is using the two configured DNS servers in round-robin (which would be fine if it marked the first as offline and stopped using it for a period of time after a failed request). Clients seem to be getting about a 50% hit rate when accessing a new host (not caches locally on their client) and often have to load pages twice in the browser to get the DNS response.

I have a good understanding about how DNS as a whole works with Authorities, Recursors and Forwarders but I don't understand how Windows clients make their decisions for which DNS server to contact and attempt to maintain availability. Is this actually documented anywhere?

This problem only seems to happen to the Windows clients in the network: Linux seems to deal with it in a sensible way and I don't get any errors - although I am unsure of the exact policy that Linux uses either.

What is the expected behavior of Windows clients when making DNS requests? Is there any configuration for the Windows DNS Cache that would improve performance/availability?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it could be a DNS cache issue

I would recommend stopping DNS client service on client